# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL from different project on App Engine flex Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, app-engine-flexible

Here's the exception that's thrown:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.`

I also get this message later on the stack trace:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Google Cloud SQL API is not enabled for project [xxxxxx]. Please use the Google Developers Console to enable it: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview?project=xxxxxx`

When I click on the console link, I can see that the Cloud SQL Api is enabled and the code was working perfectly when the database was on the same project. I also added the AppEngine flexible service account that has the `App Engine flexible environment Service Agent` role in the project containing the Cloud SQL database with the role `Cloud SQL Client`.

What should I try next ? Thanks

**UPDATE**

pom.xml:

-- update2 there's no more need for that file --

Comment: I also added the default app engine  service account (standard) with Cloud SQL Client but in vain.

Comment: Have you looked at [this article][https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql#running_sql_name_short_and_gae_name_short_in_separate_projects] explaining how to connect to Cloud SQL in a different project?

Comment: Yes I tried with the default service account and the flexible service account but both don't work.

Comment: Can you provide your full pom.xml and config.properties file contents? I would recommend omitting the personal information such as passwords.

Comment: I updated the question with the pom.xml file. PS: I am not a Java developer, I am coming from the JavaScript, Cloud and devOps world and trying to deploy this project that someone else developed. There's no config.properties file.

Comment: Please check if the API is enabled on the **other** project.

Comment: @Vadim Thank you so much, it's now working correctly. I enabled the Cloud Sql Admin API on the project that doesn't contain the database and it worked !  However, I think that the log message can be enhanced, or at least, it should be specified in the documentation.

Comment: @Vadim can you post your solution as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing existing cloud SQL instance from another project ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518780/accessing-existing-cloud-sql-instance-from-another-project-id)

Comment: well not really your link points to an IAM issue while this is an API activation issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a Cloud SQL instance in a different project, it's important that the  Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled in the source project. Copy the link in the error message and replace the project id with the other project id. The current message is misleading as it currently assumes the instance is in the same project.

Comment: Both the `Cloud SQL API` and the `Cloud SQL Admin API` need to be enabled in both of the projects.

Comment: I think the Cloud SQL Admin API is sufficient, I don't believe you need Cloud SQL API on the project that doesn't have Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are required for inter-project Cloud SQL communication:

- The project containing the Cloud SQL instance must have Cloud SQL Admin API enabled
- The project wanting to access it must have an appropriate Cloud SQL IAM role on the project containing the Cloud SQL Instance ([source](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine)):

> ### App Engine and Cloud SQL in different projects
>
> For App Engine applications and Cloud SQL instances in different projects, you must grant the default appengine service account (`[PROJECT-ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com)` one of the following IAM roles:
>
> - Cloud SQL Client
> - Cloud SQL Editor
> - Cloud SQL Admin