# Connecting To a cloud sql project from a different project using different accounts in Django Rest Framework

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

I have beet trying to connect to cloud sql on a different project in a different account but it is not working. I have tried adding the service account to the IAM permissions of the other account and enabled all the roles and yet it cannot allow me to connect to it using my project in app engine. Using cloud proxy the connection is established but in app engine is not working.**It only displays Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request**
Any contribution will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After review of my project the configurations presented [Accessing existing cloud SQL instance from another project ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518780/accessing-existing-cloud-sql-instance-from-another-project-id/23522193) works even for projects in different user accounts. The only configuration mistake was in my app.yaml file. For others with the same issue Authorization of external projects is in SQL -> connections sections